# Hello there. Cloning not works on modified image

Tags: javascript, html

*It is a simple table in which the data is entered and there are buttons for cloning and deleting.

My problem is that in the cloned row, the image is not cloned at all. the image I want to change does not change. In particular, before cloning the image is modified, after cloning both images are not modified. I think the input is not cloned

How to do??? thank you very much.*

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $(document).on('click', ".btn_row_below_new", function(e) {
    var r = $(this).closest('tr').clone();

    $.each(r.find('td'), function(i1, v1) {
      //clear all data / value in td / cell
      $(this).html('');
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').after(r);
  });
  //--->current line> new> end


  //--->current line> clone> start
  $(document).on('click', ".btn_row_below_clone", function(e) {
    var r = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(this).closest('tr').after(r);
  });
  //--->current line> clone> end

  //--->current line> delete> start
  $(document).on('click', ".btn_row_delete", function(e) {
    var r = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
  //--->current line> delete> end

});

function previewImage() {
  var file = document.getElementById("file").files;
  if (file.length > 0) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("preview").setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px;padding-top:100px;" class="container">
  <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover tbl_code_with_mark">
    <tr>
      <th>Foto</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Prezzo (€)</th>
      <th>Opzione
        <th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>

          <img id="preview" src="https://d1muf25xaso8hp.cloudfront.net/https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fappforest_uf%2Ff1595928150631x625876263392768800%2Ffoodimage.png?w=64&amp;h=64&amp;auto=compress&amp;dpr=1.25&amp;fit=max" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px; border-radius: 0px;">
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage();" style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;z-index: 15;cursor: pointer;left: 158px;width: 77px;height: 55px;top: 152px;">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><textarea data-gramm_editor="false" tabindex="49" placeholder="" maxlength="" rows="1"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea data-gramm_editor="false" tabindex="49" placeholder="" maxlength="" rows="1"></textarea></td>


      <td>
        <select>
          <option class="dropdown-choice dropdown-placeholder" value="&quot;PLACEHOLDER_1427118222253&quot;" disabled="" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107); display: none;">Tutte le categorie</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;BLANK_1427118194589&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);"></option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;fast_food&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Agroalimentare</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;healthy_food&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Aziende agricole olearie</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;traditional_food&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Aziende agricole vitivinicole</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;hamburger&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Aziende transf. agroalimentare</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;pizza&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Caseifici</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;french_frise&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Lavorazione funghi e tartufi</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;sandwich&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Macellerie, pescherie, negozi tipici</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;coffee&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Torrefazioni, industrie caffè</option>
          <option class="dropdown-choice" value="&quot;dessert&quot;" style="color: rgb(107, 107, 107);">Dessert</option>

        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" tabindex="51" placeholder="" maxlength="">
      </td>

      <td>
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_row_below_clone">Clona</span> |
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_row_delete">Elimina</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get the problem, when cloning the row the image is the same?

Comment: the row is cloned, the problem is the image of the cloned row does not make me change it

Comment: The problem is you use an absolute positioned file input underneath the image to trigger the file upload. Because it is absolute positioned with the same top and left value the input for both file upload are under the first image. You could use relative positioning instead. However I would suggest to use input labels the link to the correct input to prevent buggy situations when dimensions change.

Comment: Also you can't do id selection on the cloned elements unless you make sure the have an unique id. Id's need to be unique according to the html specification.

Comment: If my answer fully addresses your problem then please accept it (check mark to the left of the answer) as the correct answer so other people can see you don't need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed most of the css and table columns that are not relevant to your question.

I changed your preview code so it targets the right code and added a click handler on the image to target the correct file input. This solution should work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_row_below_clone', function(e) {
    var r = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(this).closest('tr').after(r);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_row_delete', function(e) {
    var r = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });

  //Added click function when you click the image the file upload click event handler is triggered.
  $(document).on('click', 'img.preview', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.img-file').trigger('click');
  });

  //Changed the change handler of the file input so it targets the correct row.
  $(document).on('change', '.img-file', function(e) {
    var file = this.files;
    if (file.length > 0) {
      var target = $(this).closest('tr').find('.preview');
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        target.attr("src", event.target.result);
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
img.preview {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.img-file {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px;padding-top:100px;" class="container">
  <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover tbl_code_with_mark">
    <tr>
      <th>Foto</th>
      <th>Opzione</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <img class="preview" src="https://d1muf25xaso8hp.cloudfront.net/https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fappforest_uf%2Ff1595928150631x625876263392768800%2Ffoodimage.png?w=64&amp;h=64&amp;auto=compress&amp;dpr=1.25&amp;fit=max">
          <input type="file" name="file" class="img-file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_row_below_clone">Clona</span> |
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_row_delete">Elimina</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```